# 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have download project from git hub when i hit

```
localhost/project/public its working
```

when i hit `php artisan serve` i got

```
[Tue Oct 30 15:26:08 2018] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Oct 30 15:26:08 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/agile/server.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

and server i got

This page isn’t working

127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

my env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Y8K7cqYOOxdk4ws+dSME+ilPPs2592UZxsHHjpfu9Dw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost/agile/
APP_TITLE=GitScrum

GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=test
GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=test

GITLAB_KEY=test
GITLAB_SECRET=test
GITLAB_INSTANCE_URI=https://gitlab.com/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=agile
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=zxzx

APP_PAGINATE=10

PROXY_PORT=
PROXY_METHOD=
PROXY_SERVER=
PROXY_USER=
PROXY_PASS=
```

htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]



 # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya i have update my code

Comment: what is your php version

Comment: have you do composer install

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta ma php version is 7.1 and i have installed composer

Comment: `composer install` in your root directory of project

Comment: in which folder you project is located, because if this is working localhost/project/public, to me sounds like your project path is in /var/www/html/project not in /var/www/html/agile/. in other words in /var/www/html/agile/ do you have server.php file?